# Android Listview setSelection(index) where the list have different items height

Tags: android

Salam
is there any way to setSelection on list where the list have different items height ?

```
list.setSelection(index);
```

because of different items height if i set list.setSelection(20) the list is going before index item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setSelectionFromTop() or setSelection(). More [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y);
listview.setSelection(int position)
```

Comment: @Hamidreza how are you setting the selection? I have used this and its working for me

Comment: list.setSelectionFromTop(index,#ListItem);